# Change values in one dataframe with values from another dataframe as a look-up-table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My first dataframe looks like this:

```
column1   column2   column3   column4
P1        D1        T1        1.0
P1        D2        T2        2.0
P1        D3        T1        3.0
P1        D4        T2        4.0
P2        D1        T1        5.0
P2        D2        T2        6.0
P2        D3        T1        7.0
P2        D4        T2        8.0
```

My second dataframe that looks like this:

```
column1      Name1      Name2    Name3    Name4
    P1        D2        D3        D4      D1
    P2        D1        D4        D3      D2
```

I want to add a new column to the first dataframe that shows in which column I can find the value of its second column so It will become like this:

```
column1   column2   column3   column4   column5
P1        D1        T1        1.0       Name4
P1        D2        T2        2.0       Name1
P1        D3        T1        3.0       Name2
P1        D4        T2        4.0       Name3
P2        D1        T1        5.0       Name1
P2        D2        T2        6.0       Name4
P2        D3        T1        7.0       Name3
P2        D4        T2        8.0       Name2
```

Right now, I have a nested for loop that goes through each value in the first column and each value on the second column of the first dataframe, finds the corresponding column in the second dataframe and writes it in the new column. I am wondering if there is a more elegant solution to this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First `melt` (un-pivot) `df2`. Then `merge` it with `df1`:

```
df2 = df2.melt(id_vars='column1', value_name='column2', var_name='column5')
df1 = df1.merge(df2, on=['column1', 'column2'])
```

```
print(df1)
  column1 column2 column3  column4 column5
0      P1      D1      T1      1.0   Name4
1      P1      D2      T2      2.0   Name1
2      P1      D3      T1      3.0   Name2
3      P1      D4      T2      4.0   Name3
4      P2      D1      T1      5.0   Name1
5      P2      D2      T2      6.0   Name4
6      P2      D3      T1      7.0   Name3
7      P2      D4      T2      8.0   Name2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `melt` and `merge`, then `reindex` to order same as `df1`:

```
(df2.melt('column1',value_name='column2',var_name='column5')
  .merge(df1,on=['column1','column2'])
  .set_index(['column1','column2'])
  .reindex(df1.set_index(['column1','column2']).index)
 .reset_index().sort_index(axis=1))
```

---

```
  column1 column2 column3  column4 column5
0      P1      D1      T1      1.0   Name4
1      P1      D2      T2      2.0   Name1
2      P1      D3      T1      3.0   Name2
3      P1      D4      T2      4.0   Name3
4      P2      D1      T1      5.0   Name1
5      P2      D2      T2      6.0   Name4
6      P2      D3      T1      7.0   Name3
7      P2      D4      T2      8.0   Name2
```